# How to change the marker symbol of errorbar limits in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, errorbar

just a quick question, where I couldn't find anything helpful in the [`plt.errorbar` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html)

I want to plot values with error bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar(1, 0.25, yerr=0.1, uplims=True, lolims=True, fmt='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I would like to have error bars with a simple horizontal line instead of arrows at the ends. But there is no "capmarker" or similar option in the `plt.errorbar()` function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `uplims=True` and `lolims=True`; both limits are plotted by default, without any ending arrows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.errorbar(1, 0.25, yerr=0.1, fmt='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Increase the *capsize* to add caps to the end of the error bars, and increase the *capthick* to make the caps thicker:

```
plt.errorbar(1, 0.25, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', capsize=3)
```

[image]

```
plt.errorbar(1, 0.25, yerr=0.1, fmt='o', capsize=3, capthick=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Sorry my description was misleading. I want to have horizontal lines at the end of the colorbars instead of arrows.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks @BigBen, this should be better explained/showcased in the documentation